# Clearing cell contents prevent next button to be added

Tags: vba, excel

I want to replace some cell values with buttons, but clearing the value prevents next button to be added. Here's the script:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim btn As Button
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each cell In Sh.UsedRange.Cells
            If cell.Value = "{magic_value}" Then
                Set btn = Sh.Buttons.Add(cell.Left, cell.Top, cell.Width, cell.Height)
                With btn
                    .OnAction = "ButtonClickHandler"
                    .Caption = "Btn_" & cell.Left & "_" & cell.Top
                    .Name = "Btn_" & cell.Left & "_" & cell.Top
                End With
                cell.ClearContents ' everything works without this line
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

When I open a workbook, first button is added but next buttons are not, and `Runtime error '1004'` occurs: `Unable to get property Add of class Buttons` (my translation). And debugger points to the line `Set btn = Sh.Buttons.Add ...`

From my research, the reason is the line `cell.ClearContents`. But I can't imagine how an error is related to a cell clearing.

Comment: Have you try a workaround for `cell.ClearContents`? Like using the others `.Clear*` (`.Clear`, `.ClearFormats`, ...) or simply by using `cell.Value=vbNullString`?

Comment: probably .ClearContents invalidate the iteration on .UsedRange.Cells. Try @R3uK sugestions. Alternatively first "fix" the range in another variable and only then go iterate

Comment: @R3uK I've just tried all of them. No change. Also tried `cell.Value=""`

Comment: @qPCR4vir Don't get what you mean about "fixing" the range. Can you show?

Comment: Like @qPCR4vir suggested, create a **Range** variable and use `Set varRange = Sh.UsedRange.Cells` between your 2 first `For Each` and use this variable in your 2nd `For Each` (`For Each cell In Sh.UsedRange.Cells` become `For Each cell In varRange`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but the problem was in the code I didn't show you:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Sh.Unprotect pwd
    Target.Locked = False
    Sh.Protect pwd
End Sub
```

Updating cell's value raised SheetChange event. My solution is to temporarily disable events:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
...

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your code works perfectly fine on my computer, I could understand if there is an issue with the `Button` collection. If you go into the Object Browser you will see that the `Button` collection is hidden. I am not sure if this collection will be depreciated. Yet, it also caused me some problems in the past. Why don't you try this instead:

```
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each cell In Sh.UsedRange.Cells
        If cell.Value = "{magic_value}" Then
            Sh.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlButtonControl, cell.Left, cell.Top, cell.EntireColumn.Width, cell.EntireRow.Height).Name = _
                "Btn_" & cell.Left & "_" & cell.Top
            Sh.Shapes("Btn_" & cell.Left & "_" & cell.Top).OnAction = "ButtonClickHandler"
            cell.ClearContents ' everything works without this line
        End If
    Next
Next
```

The name and the caption are identical in this (the above) case and the on_click action is automatically assigned to these form controls.

Comment: Sorry, forgot one line in the code. Now the `.OnAction` event handler is added correctly.

Comment: BTW: these are merely `shapes`. Note, that almost **any** shape in Excel can get a macro assigned and most of these `shapes` look better than a button: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333488/vba-windows-7-style-buttons/32335204#32335204