# Create Progress bar in Excel without using User Form

Tags: vba, excel

I want to Know, How to create progress bar in excel vba without form.

I have added the MS progress bar but I want know how to run while running my macro

Thanks in advance

Am using the below Code But the position is in the top, I want to  move it to some other How can I do it?

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long, nextT As Single
Dim pb As ProgressBar

Set pb = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ProgressBar21").Object

pb.Value = 0
pb.Visible = True

For i = 1 To 100
nextT = Timer + 0.05
While Timer < nextT
Wend
nextT = Timer
pb.Value = i
Next
pb.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some relevant piece of code to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Yes I have Updated the Code

Comment: AFAIK, you have no control over its location if you embed it on a worksheet. Why can't you just embed it on a form?

Comment: I am not sure what you don't want to use a form. But there are tons of shapes in Excel which could be used to look like a progress bar. You can also use them as buttons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333488/vba-windows-7-style-buttons/32335204#32335204

Comment: Hi Guys Thanks for your time Now able to do it, By Moving the Progressbar manually. to My desired location

Comment: Would you mind adding the solution to this question so that others can learn. It doesn't much help if others do a Google search and get here just to find out that there is no solution to the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ralph, As I mentioned in the above comment, I just Manually move the Progress bar in the excel sheet to my desired place, That's it it started working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just Manually move the Progress bar in the excel sheet to my desired place, That's it it started working.

Note: After I executing the code once I moved  the Progress bar location.